# Why do emails sent using sendgrid always have a HASH appended at the end?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, sendgrid

I am sending emails using sendgrid from my asp.net MVC application. I'm not sure from where, but ALL the emails I send have a mysterious text appended at the end that looks like "HASH(0x5310130)".

I am sure I'm not appending this in my website code. Does anyone have a clue as to why this is happening and how I can avoid this? Anyone else having similar issue?

Thanks and Cheers!
2P

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I noticed the HASH when sending from Azure.

Comment: Nope :-(. Still have the same issue. Were you able to resolve it so far?

Comment: Please paste your SendGrid code here. So it will be helpful to resolve your issue. Thanks! Note:- Hide credential and then paste the code, if any.

Comment: Please share a snippet to make it easier for someone to help you

Comment: I used sendgrid within the last 6 months (and for a year prior) and never saw such a thing. I would suspect it is in your sending software, though I understand you say no way. Maybe try another service and see?

Answer (score 0):

It's a very wild guess but could this be something used by Sendgrid to track if the recipient opened the email ?